# Clear all cronjobs via ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have been making cron jobs like this

```
  - name: Add in cronjob to run every 30 mins to update do cool things
    cron:
      name="Run cool.py"
      minute="30"
      job="cd /home/www/ && . env/bin/activate && python /home/www/cool.py >/dev/null 2>&1"
      user=cooluser
```

Now I'd like to know, how to delete all the cronjobs in my ubuntu box.  Since I've made a few while testing and want to start fresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways. If you want to do it "correctly", you set `state: absent` on all cronjobs and run the playbook:

```yaml
  - name: Add in cronjob to run every 30 mins to update do cool things
    cron:
      name: "Run cool.py"
      user: cooluser
      state: absent
```

You need to set them for each cronjob you created, they are matched by `name`. Check the [docs of the cron module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html).

If you just want to remove all the crontabs for a certain user, you can ssh to that box and run `crontab -r -u cooluser`. This will remove all jobs for `cooluser`, but leave everything in `/etc/` untouched. But ansible does not add anything there.

If you want to do that, but use ansible, you can use the [command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html):

```yaml
- name: remove all cronjobs for user cooluser
  command: crontab -r -u cooluser
```

The first one is the one you should use in a production playbook. The other two can be used, if you just want to do a one-time cleanup to start fresh.

You can also check `crontab -l -u cooluser` to see all currently available cronjobs and `crontab -e -u cooluser` to edit them.